# How to apply the same function to multiple lists

Tags: python, list

I have two lists and want to apply the same function to both, I know how to apply one at a time, but not both? Then I want to add each element to gather a total?

```
a = ['a','b','c','d','e']
b = ['b', np.nan,'c','e','a']
c = ['a','b','c','d','e']
```

I know you could do below to get the output, but I wanted to do it with serparation

```
a = [1 if 'a' in a else 99 for x in a]
b = [1 if 'a' in b else 99 for x in b]
c = [1 if 'a' in c else 99 for x in c]
```

I first want to outputs below:

```
a = [1, 99, 99, 99, 99]
b = [99, 99, 99, 99, 1]
c = [99, 99, 99, 99, 1]
```

Then Add each elements into one final list

```
sum = [199, 297, 297, 297, 101]
```

Comment: I think you mistyped your list comprehension, it sounds like you meant `[1 if x == 'a' else 99 for x in a]` and so forth (for b and c). Might want to correct that, otherwise it might be hard for people to understand what you're trying to achieve. Also clarify what you mean with "separation". Do you mean DRY? As in, not having to retype your criteria many times over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I understood your question correctly. As [fgblomqvist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/998919/fgblomqvist) commented, I replaced `1 if 'a' in a` by `1 if x == 'a'` in the list comprehension. Then I basically reproduced your second step with a for-loop and after that I used [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate over the list values of all lists synchronously in order to calculate the sum.

```py
a = ['a','b','c','d','e']
b = ['b','a','c','e','a']
c = ['a','b','c','d','e']

# add the lists to a list. 
lists = [a,b,c]

outcomes = []
for l in lists:
    outcome = [1 if x == 'a' else 99 for x in l]
    outcomes.append(outcome)
    print(f'one of the outcomes: {outcome}')


results = []

# iterate over all list values synchronously and  calculate the sum
for outs in zip(*outcomes):
    results.append(sum(outs))
    print(f'sum of {outs} is {sum(outs)}')

print(f'final result:{results}')
```

This is the output:

```py
one of the outcomes: [1, 99, 99, 99, 99]
one of the outcomes: [99, 1, 99, 99, 1]
one of the outcomes: [1, 99, 99, 99, 99]
sum of (1, 99, 1) is 101
sum of (99, 1, 99) is 199
sum of (99, 99, 99) is 297
sum of (99, 99, 99) is 297
sum of (99, 1, 99) is 199
final result:[101, 199, 297, 297, 199]
```

edit: To avoid looping twice you could join the loops together like so:

```py
lists = [a,b,c]

sums = []
for values in zip(*lists):
    the_sum = 0
    for val in values:
        the_sum += 1 if val == 'a' else 99
    sums.append(the_sum)

print(f'sums: {sums}')
```

Keep in mind you can replace the `1 if val == 'a' else 99` by `some_func(val)`

Answer (score 0):

pandas makes this quite easy
(although im sure its amost as easy just with numpy)

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({'a':a,'b':b,'c':c})
mask = df == 'a'
df[mask] = 1
df[~mask] = 99
df.sum(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

a = ['a','b','c','d','e']
b = ['b', np.nan,'c','e','a']
c = ['a','b','c','d','e']

dct = {"a":1}

sum_var = [np.nansum([dct.get(aa,99), dct.get(bb,99), dct.get(cc,99)]) for (aa, bb, cc) in zip(a,b,c)]
```

Explaination:
You can use list comprehension (as you did in your example) with a bit of modification. Instead of iterating through a single list, iterate through a collection of all the lists. You can achive this by using the builtin function "zip()" which essentially zips the lists together.

Since all 3 lists have the same length you can iterate through it and apply additional transformations on each element like shown in the example.
The additional function in this example is the dictionary.get() method which gets you the value for each key, here the 1 for an "a". Everything which is not in the dictionary will return a 99. But in the same way you can use custom made functions.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26239326)

Comment: @double-beep Thank your for the constructive critism. I get your point and you are right. I will add some explaination and keep it in mind for the future.